# Как CGlib работает с final методами?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

У меня есть условно вот такой сервис:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    private final ThreadLocal<SomeData> threadLocalData = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Transactional
    public void someProcess() {
        // некоторая логика
    }

    public final SomeData pull() {
        SomeData data = threadLocalData.get();
        threadLocalData.remove();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Из-за того, что в сервисе открывается транзакция *(и из-за того, что сервис не реализует какого-либо интерфейса)*, сервис оборачивается в прокси CGlib. Из-за этого у меня была проблема с вызовом метода `pull()` из других сервисов, потому что возникала ошибка NullPointerException из-за того, что поле `threadLocalData` в прокси было null.

Это нормальное и ожидаемое поведения. Однако меня интересует вот что: как именно обрабатываются финальные методы при компиляции CGlib? Потому что вот как я представляю себе прокси, получаемое из моего объекта:

```
@Service
public class SomeService$$CGlibProxy extends SomeService {
    SomeService someService;

    @Override
    public void someProcess() {
        // создание транзакции
        someService.someProcess();
        // закрытие транзакции
    }

    ???
}
```

То есть понятно, что прокси копирует все поля родителя *(при этом все они null)*. И также понятно, что происходит с методом `someProcess` *(некоторая логика до, вызов реального метода, некоторая логика после)*.

Но что происходит с методом `pull()`? Он финальный, но при этом CGlib не даёт ошибку, и у прокси этот метод вызывается, причём ещё и обращается к полю `threadLocalData` в самой прокси.

Как создаётся и как выглядит метод `pull()` в прокси?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не сразу догадался, в принципе ответ на поверхности.

Так как прокси наследуется от реального класса, а финальные методы не переопределяются, то в данном случае вызывается метод `pull()` родителя. Но так как в прокси все наследуемые поля имеют значение null, то вызов метода выбрасывает исключение.